# BarcodeScanner isn't loading/showing

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner

I installed the barcode plugin for phone gap and followed all the instructions.
But when I launch the application and press the button to start scanning for a code, it doesn't do anything.

Imported all the files, added it the plugins,...

Still no luck. It just doesn't do anything and I'm also aint getting any error messages.

Anyone has any idea of why it doesn't load/show ?

Using latest phone gap (cordova) and iOS 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the current version of the iOS barcode scanner plugin was tested with Phonegap not higher than 1.5.0.

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/msg/7a56c9de171050a1

To make initial tests just follow the instructions from the link above:

1. add Phonegap 1.5.0 to xCode
2. unzip the xCode project below and run it on a physical device with a webcam: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner/Example

If this is working you can try the same in your own project.